# Fluent NHibernate - Filtering resultset

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

FNH Newbie question -

I have two objects RR and TT defined as following:

```
public class RR
{
   Id
   Name
   TT_Id //corresponds to TT.Id
}

public class TT
{
   Id
   Name
   Type   
}
```

I want to filter records from RR as per following SQL:

```
SELECT RR.*
FROM RR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TT ON RR.TT_Id = TT.Id
WHERE TT.Type <> 7
```

Can anyone please guide how can I add filter criteria to achieve above in NH.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you have **TT_Id** and not **TT** itself in **RR**? IMO it will make a lot of things more difficult than needed.

if it would reference to **TT** then

```
resultlist = session.CreateCriteria<RR>()
    .CreateCriteria("TT")
    .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Type", 7)))
    .List<RR>();
```

otherwise

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<TT>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Type", 7)))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id());

resultlist = session.CreateCriteria<RR>()
    .Add(Subqueries.In("TT_id", subquery)))
    .List<RR>();
```

or

```
IList<object[]> resultlist = session.CreateSqlQuery("SELECT RR.* FROM RR LEFT OUTER JOIN TT ON R.TT_Id = TT.Id WHERE TT.Type <> 7 ")
    .List().Cast<object[]>();

// hydrate RR yourself here
```

Comment: Hi Firo, Thanks for your response. Well, I am trying with DetachedCriteria as you have suggested above, but getting this error:

Comment: error - cannot convert from 'NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria' to 'object[]' at this line: criterions.Add(Restrictions.In("TT_id", subQuery));  Herez my code snippet: IList<ICriterion> criterions = new List<ICriterion>();
criterions.Add(Restrictions.In("TT_id", subQuery)); IMultiCriteria c = session.CreateMultiCriteria();
c.ApplyStrategy<RR>(criterions, strategy.StrategyElements);

Comment: @iniki sorry copy-paste error edited **Restrictions** to **Subqueries**